# Solve ODE with infinite series

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, polynomials

Let $\pi(x)$ be an analytic function of  $x$:

\begin{equation}
\pi(x_{t})=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x_t ^{n}
\end{equation}

I want to solve the following ODE:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \pi^{\prime \prime} (x_t) - \lambda k \pi (x_t) \pi^\prime(x_t) - \delta \pi (x_t) + k x_t = 0
\end{equation}

My initial condition is that $x_0$ is given. If we replace $\pi(x_{t})$ with $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x_t^{n}$ in the ODE and compare coefficients for $x_t$, we can see that a solution is: $a_n=0$ $\forall n \in N_0 - \{1\}$ and $a_1$ satisfies:

\begin{equation}
\lambda k a_1^2 + \delta a_1 - k = 0
\end{equation}

I would like Mathematica to output this result but I don't know how to do it. Any suggestions?

I have attempted the standard approach, but it does not work:

```
f[x_] := Sum[a[n]*x^n, {n, 0, Infinity}]

DSolve[1/2 σ^2 D[f[x], {x, 2}] - λ k f[x] D[f[x], {x, 1}] - δ f[x] + k x == 0, f[x], x]
```

Picture of the code:

[image]

Comment: The code is not broken. When you paste it back to _Mathematica_, it'll relives. If you also want to make it look nice in this site, first press Ctrl+Shift+I to transform it to `InputForm`, for more info check this post: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1585/1871 In short: please show us the code text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you're not solving the ODE with infinite series **in usual sense**. This approach is easy to automate in *Mathematica*. Notice that strictly speaking, $x_t$ should not be zero:

```
test[x_] = a1 x;

Simplify[
  1/2 σ^2 D[f[x], {x, 2}] - λ k f[x] D[f[x], {x, 1}] - δ f[x] + k x == 0 /. f -> test, 
  x != 0] // Expand
(* a1 δ + a1^2 k λ == k *)
```

Answer (score 10):

Please post code in plain text format next time. Not an image only. It is not good idea to use $\pi$ as function name so I changed it to $f$ below.

To find series solution of ode in Mathematica, use the command `AsymptoticDSolveValue`

```
Clear["Global`*"]
ode = 1/2*σ^2 f''[x] - λ *k* f[x]*f'[x] - δ*f[x] + k*x == 0

AsymptoticDSolveValue[ode, f[x], {x, 0, 6}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> If I canche pi to f I do not obtain the result you posted

You must have done something wrong. It does not matter that the function is called.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
ode = 1/2*σ^2 pi''[x] - λ*k*pi[x]*pi'[x] - δ*pi[x] + k*x == 0

AsymptoticDSolveValue[ode, pi[x], {x, 0, 6}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> Besides this, should I be able to read your result in a way that
> confirms my solution?

I do not understand what you wrote below

---

and $a_1$ satisfies:

\begin{equation}
\lambda k a^2 + \delta a - k = 0
\end{equation}

---

How could $a_1$ have that value? In second order ode, $a_0,a_1$ are always arbitrary. These correspond to the two initial conditions. i.e. given two initial conditions, only then can they be found. So to answer your question $a_1$ is just $a_1$ and $a_0$ is just $a_0$.  You could find all the higher $a_n$ terms if you want as follows. Lets use a simple ode first to make it more clear what is going on.

```
 ode = f''[x] - f[x] == 0;
```

The series solution is

```
 sol=AsymptoticDSolveValue[{ode},f[x],{x,0,8}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In the above $c_1$ and $c_2$ is what we call $a_0,a_1$ in the series. But Mathematica likes to use $c_1,c_2$ instead. To check that is true, do

```
eq1 = (sol /. x -> 0) == g[x] /. x -> 0;
eq1 = Solve[eq1, C[1]][[1, 1]]
eq2 = (D[sol, x] /. x -> 0) == D[g[x], x] /. x -> 0;
eq2 = Solve[eq2, C[2]][[1, 1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To find all $a_n$ terms, you can apply the above method of repeated differentiation as follows

```
Clear["Global`*"]
ode = f''[x] - f[x] == 0;
g[x_] := Sum[a[n] x^n, {n, 0, 8}];
sol = AsymptoticDSolveValue[{ode}, f[x], {x, 0, 8}]
eq1 = (sol /. x -> 0) == g[x] /. x -> 0;
eq1 = Solve[eq1, C[1]][[1, 1]]
eq2 = (D[sol, x] /. x -> 0) == D[g[x], x] /. x -> 0;
eq2 = Solve[eq2, C[2]][[1, 1]]

aTerms = First@Last@Reap@Do[
     eq = ((D[sol, {x, n}] /. x -> 0) == D[g[x], {x, n}] /. 
         x -> 0) /. {eq1, eq2};
     Sow[Solve[eq, a[n]][[1, 1]]]
     ,
     {n, 2, 6}
     ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You see, each $a_n$ for $n>1$ is expressed in terms of $a_0$ or $a_1$. The series solution itself is

```
g[x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So to evaluate do

```
g[x] /. aTerms
Collect[%, {a[0], a[1]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare the above to what Mathematica gave which is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You see they are the same (add more terms if you want). The above now gives you a way to find $a_n$. By inspection here we see that

$$
a_{n+2} = \frac{a_n}{(n+2)(n+1}
$$

For example for $n=0$ the above gives $a_2 =\frac{a_0}{2} $ and for $n=1$ it gives $a_3 =\frac{a_1}{6} $  and so on. Using the above recursive formula all $a_n$ can be found.

Now for your specific ode, you can do the same

```
Clear["Global`*"]
ode = 1/2*σ^2 f''[x] - λ *k* f[x]*f'[x] - δ*f[x] + k*x == 0;
g[x_] := Sum[a[n] x^n, {n, 0, 8}];
g[x]
sol = AsymptoticDSolveValue[{ode}, f[x], {x, 0, 8}]
eq1 = (sol /. x -> 0) == g[x] /. x -> 0;
eq1 = Solve[eq1, C[1]][[1, 1]]
eq2 = (D[sol, x] /. x -> 0) == D[g[x], x] /. x -> 0;
eq2 = Solve[eq2, C[2]][[1, 1]]

aTerms = First@Last@Reap@Do[
     eq = ((D[sol, {x, n}] /. x -> 0) == D[g[x], {x, n}] /. 
         x -> 0) /. {eq1, eq2};
     Sow[Solve[eq, a[n]][[1, 1]]]
     ,
     {n, 2, 6}
     ]
```

The $a_n$ terms are

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can now see what the relation between them is.  Finding the recursive formula for the above is not easy. But you see that

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I do not know if this is what you were asking for or not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I canche pi to f I do not obtain the result you posted. Besides this, should I be able to read your result in a way that confirms my solution?

Comment: I have updated my answer as it was not clear: what I meant is that the ODE is satisfied if we postulate that $a_n = zero$ for all $n$ except 1, and $a_1$ satisfies the quadratic

Comment: I have also clarified that my initial condition is that $x_0$ is given.